# Retrieval of the Inspected elements and manipulating them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have the following component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { Box } from '@mui/system';
import { InputBase, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import { NoEncryption } from "@mui/icons-material";
type Props = {
    issueId: string
}

export default function DialogBox({ issueId }: Props) {

    const myTheme = createTheme({
        // Set up your custom MUI theme here
    })


    const [newMsg, setNewMsg] = React.useState("");
    const [startNewMsg, setStartNewMsg] = React.useState(false)



    const handleNewMsgInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    }

    const handleKeyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        if (event.key === "Escape") {
            // setStartNewMsg(false);
            setNewMsg((prev) => "");
        }
    }


    return (
        <Box flexDirection="column" sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "lightblue", height: "100%", gap: "2rem" }} onKeyPress={(e) => {
            handleKeyPress(e)
        }}>
            <Typography
                sx={{
                    width: "fit-content",
                    height: "fit-content",
                    fontFamily: "Amatic SC",
                    background: "lightblue",
                    fontSize: "3rem"
                }}>
                Message board
            </Typography>
            {startNewMsg ?
                <Box sx={{ width: "fit-content", height: "fit-content" }}>
                    <ReactQuill style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: "10rem", maxWidth: "30rem", maxHeight: "10rem" }} theme="snow" />
                </Box>
                :

                <TextField id="filled-basic" label="write new message" sx={{ "& fieldset": { border: 'none' }, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "5px" }} variant="filled" fullWidth={true} onClick={(e) => setStartNewMsg((prev) => true)} onChange={(e) => handleNewMsgInput(e)} />}

        </Box >
    )
}
```

Which's causing me the following issue of text appearing out of my white textbox:

[image]

I notice on inspection the following property which's responsible for the problem:
[image]

My question is, what would be the best way to manipulating the values of that element? How should I retrieve them?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ch` units (the size of the text characters) and adjust the size based on the input.

**Example:**

```js
const Test = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={text}
        onChange= {(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        style= {{height: `${text.length}ch`, width: `${text.length}ch`}}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

^ that is an input box that will grow based on the size of the text.

---

You don't want:

```css
height: 100%;
```

as this will only allow the height to be as big as its parent container.

Comment: Hi. I'm aware that I don't want it to be 100%, yet I'm not sure how to set it. When I use the style props, I deliver there a height of 10rem, but that's of the total component and not the specific white-box for the text. What I try is to shrink the height of that paragraph attribute which the component contains.